# Sinonjs: how to mock Backbone fetch

Tags: backbone.js, sinon

I use Backbone and have the following function in accountsView.js:

```
loadData: function () {

            this.accountsCollection.fetch()
                .done(_.bind(this.loadDefaultAccounts, this))
                .fail(_.bind(this._accountsLoadFailed, this));
        },
```

In qunit test I'm trying to mock it like this:

```
sandbox.stub(Backbone.Collection.prototype, "fetch").yieldsTo("done", {});
```

But get the following error while running test:

> "fetch expected to yield to 'done', but no object with such a property
>   was passed."

What I missed?

Comment: the `.fetch` function accepts an `options` object where you can pass a `success` and `error` callback with the `context` to use. e.g. `.fetch({context: this, success: this.loadDefaultAccounts});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks for hints. In order to my test works the function in the view should like this:

```
loadData: function () {

            this.accountsCollection.fetch({
                success: _.bind(this.loadDefaultAccounts, this),
                error: _.bind(this._accountsLoadFailed, this),
            });                
        },
```

Or using in tests fake server as @TJ suggested.

Answer (score 1):

`yieldsTo` looks to me like it's meant to deal with callback based code.

To mock AJAX  requests, you should setup a [fake server](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.1.0/fake-xhr-and-server/) and do something like

```
this.server.respondWith("GET", "/some/article/comments.json",
        [200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
         '[{ "id": 12, "comment": "Hey there" }]']);
```